# .htaccess rewrite based on whether a file exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory with a bunch of javascript files. I needed to produce one of the files using PHP. So I renamed `myfile.js` to `myfile.js.php` and added this rule to `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule myfile\.js$ myfile.js.php
```

This way, the URL of the javascript file is still `http://www.example.com/directory/myfile.js` just like it was when I was serving a static file.

The rule I have works. But I am not happy with having to hardcode the filename. I'd like to write a rule that if a request comes in for any `filename.js` and the file `filename.js.php` (note .js.php extension) exists, I want to rewrite filename.js to filename.js.php.

Comment: If your calling the JS file from a php script why not use the logic within php.. seems silly to try to handle that with .htaccess.

Comment: @RyanChurchill I am not calling the JS file from a php script. Web browser requests http://www.example.com/directory/myfile.js. The URL is all over the place and is difficult to change. With .htaccess, I can keep the old URL, but the script I return to the user can now be produced dynamically.

Comment: Why don't you create a php file to handle these requests.   Such as handler.php   then when the browser requests  handler.php?jsfile=myfile.js  you can easily handle request and logic through the handler. You can write the cases within that php file to keep the paths hidden.  That is how I would approach it..

Comment: @RyanChurchill. I don't want to change the URL to handler.php?jsfile=myfile.js. I already have an established URL of http://example.com/directory/myfile.js that I'd like to keep. I already solved this for one file. It works great. I am just looking for a more generic rule that does not hardcode filenames. So that in the future I can just create a file, say foo.js.php and it will be automatically used to service a request for foo.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to htaccess

```
RewriteCond $1.js.php -f
RewriteRule ([\w\-]+)\.js$ $1.js.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, Sreedev. Can I put this rule in my top-level .htaccess and use .js.php files in any subdirectories? Or do I need to put it in the same directory with the files?

Comment: Glad it worked. You should place it in the directory containing js files.